# How to pass integer value as a parameter in http header using Alamofire in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, alamofire, swift4

I want to make an api call to fetch data from server but in this I need to set 'id' parameter as http header and is a integer value. I'm using Alamofire for network calls, swift and xcode 9.

Alternate ways will also work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the id value in string form, as if you check the Alamofire request headers is in fo`headers: HTTPHeaders?`.
And if you jump to HTTPHeaders it is:

```
/// A dictionary of headers to apply to a `URLRequest`.
    public typealias HTTPHeaders = [String: String]
```

So you can send headers as:

```
let headers = ["id": "\(yourIDValue)"]
```

and pass this headers in request method call. Also add any other key and respective values in same headers

**EDIT:**

use NSURLMutableRequest, and then set values for http header field.

```
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.addValue(yourIDValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "id")
```

pass this request to Alamofire.

Comment: I'm aware of 'public typealias HTTPHeaders = [String: String]' but I want to pass Integer as value and a string format.

Comment: did you tried code:  let headers = ["id": "\(yourIDValue)"]

Comment: Yes I've tried '["id": "(yourIDValue)"] ' but it won't work because the value is actually passed as string only.